# Convert general optimization problem to LP problem

Tags: linear-programming, nonlinear-optimization, global-optimization

I am trying to convert the following problem into a linear programming problem:

There are  $M\times N$ matrix $T$ of real numbers between 0 and 1 and $N\times 1$ vector  $w$ of real numbers between 0 and 1.

Find $w$ that minimises $\sum_{i=1}^{M}\sum_{j=1}^{N}(\hat{t}_{i,j} - t^{*}_{i,j})$ Subject to $\sum{w_i}=1$. $t^{*}_{i,j}$ are elements of matrix $T^{*}$, obtained from matrix $T$, by sorting its rows in descending order according to elements of vector $T \times w$.  $\hat{t}$ are elements of matrix $\hat{T}$,
obtained from matrix $T$ by sorting its columns independently in descending order.

For example, if $w=\begin{pmatrix} 0.5\\0.5 \end{pmatrix}$,$T=\begin{pmatrix} 0.1&0.1\\0.3&0.2\\ 0.2&0.1 \end{pmatrix}$, then $T\times w=\begin{pmatrix} 0.1\\0.25\\0.15 \end{pmatrix}$,$T^{*}=\begin{pmatrix} 0.3&0.2\\0.2&0.1\\ 0.1&0.1 \end{pmatrix}$, $\hat{T}=\begin{pmatrix} 0.3&0.2\\0.2&0.1\\ 0.1&0.1 \end{pmatrix}$

Answer (score 1):

First off, since your problem involves sorting, I doubt it can be reduced to a linear programming problem. However, it can be reduced to a mixed-integer quadratically constrained programming (MIQCP) problem as explained below.

A key element in this reduction is the ability to obtain the $k$-th [order statistic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_statistic) for a list of expressions $a_1, \dots, a_M$ (e.g., with $a_i$ being the $i$-th element of the vector $T\cdot w$).

Let us introduce an $M\times M$ matrix of binary variables $p_{i,j}\in\{0,1\}$ such that each row/column contains exactly one 1 and $p_{i,j}=1$ iff in a sorted list of $a_1, \dots, a_M$ in non-increasing order, element $a_i$ appears at position $j$. That is, $p_{i,j}$ is defined by the following system of (in)equalities
$$\begin{cases}
\sum_{j=1}^M p_{i,j} = 1,& i=1,2,\dots,M;\\
\sum_{i=1}^M p_{i,j} = 1,& j=1,2,\dots,M;\\
\sum_{i=1}^M a_i\cdot p_{i,j} \leq \sum_{i=1}^M a_i\cdot p_{i,j+1}, & j=1,2,\dots,M-1.
\end{cases}$$
Then the $k$-th order statistic of $a_1, \dots, a_M$ equals
$$\sum_{i=1}^M a_i\cdot p_{i,k}.$$

This approach allows one to explicitly express the entities $\hat t_{i,j}$ and $t^*_{i,j}$ by the price of adding new binary variables and the corresponding linear/quadratic constraints.